# Дубли страниц Opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: url, opencart, seo, opencart2.0

Доброго времени суток. 
Дело в том , что я перечитал уже все ветки Stackoverflow , и гугл . Ничего не помогло, точнее после установки SeoPro всё исправилось , но возник конфликт с Mega Filter PRO. Когда выбираешь параметр для фильтрации, он к ссылке через JavaScript добавляет `/mfp/strana-proizvoditel,Англия` после обновления страницы или перехода на неё по ссылке , выдаёт 404 , так как SeoPro на все неизвестные ссылки ставит правило для выдачи 404. В итоге одна проблема решена , но появилась другая. (Решить мне её не удаётся).

Если убирать SeoPro , то проблем с фильтром нет , но остаются страницы двух типов :

1-тип страниц)  Первая страница: `site.com/page`
Вторая: `site.com/page1` Это возникает из-за того , что заказчик добавил одну и ту же подкатегорию к нескольким родителям (Вариант удаления этой подкатегории у какого-либо родителя к сожалению не принимается заказчиком)

2-тип страниц) Первая страница: `site.com/category1/subcat`
Вторая: `site.com/category2/subcat`
На такой вариант я ставил модификатор , но этот модификатор решает проблему только при прямом нажатии в элемента меню, а при вставке ссылки в адресную строку он не редеректит.

Очень надеюсь на вас     :)

Answer (score 1):

Закрывайте дублирующие урлы в `robots.txt`, если уж до заказчика не получается донести важность отсутствия дублей на сайте и архиважность наличия грамотной структуры. Так вы немного подыграете поисковым машинам. А для клиента, как показывает практика, это всё не имеет никакого интереса.

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том , как закрыть эту дыру под капотом , чтобы руками не прописывать все эти страницы.